# i want the largest number from array in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, max

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT `id` FROM `order` where `customer`='$id'");
while ($result=$select->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo $result['id'];                                                                                                    
}
```

I got the two values.

How to print the large number ?
php max function is not working for me

Comment: use php max() function to get the maximum value from array as `echo max($your_array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also take the max of id using sql as

```
SELECT max(id) FROM order where customer='$id'
```

Answer (score 3):

faster to do it in the query:

```
SELECT id FROM order where customer='$id' order by id desc Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do in query check below query for the same.

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT id FROM order where customer='$id' order by id desc limit 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your way

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT `id` FROM `order` where `customer`='$id'");
$maxVal = 0;
while ($result=$select->fetch_assoc()) { 
    if($maxVal<$result['id']){
        $maxVal=$result['id'];
    }                                                                                                    
}
echo $maxVal;
```

But better is

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT max(id) FROM order where customer='$id'");
$result=$select->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['id'];
```

Or if your id is  auto-increment then you can use

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT id FROM order where customer='$id' order by id desc Limit 1");
$result=$select->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['id'];
```